# Is this a good candidate for plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Several of the introductory tutorials I've read on using for loops in plpgsql have said unless I *really* need a for loop, I should find another way.

As a programming novice I can't figure out a better way than a for loop.

I would like to go through each parcel gid, calculate the nearest street intersection by bounding box, then assign the intersection id to the nearest_intersection column in parcels.

All the parts of this function work nicely.  But I can't figure out how to put them together.

```
BEGIN

FOR gid IN SELECT gid FROM parcels 
LOOP
UPDATE parcels SET nearest_intersection = 
    (select intersection.osm_id
     from intersections
     order by
     intersections.geom <-> (select geom from parcels where gid = parcel_id)
     limit 1;)
end loop;
end;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, the loop doesn't make sense indeed because the `UPDATE` alone already processes every row of the `parcels` table.

What you probably want is (without a loop):

```
UPDATE parcels R SET nearest_intersection = 
    (select intersection.osm_id
     from intersections
     order by intersections.geom <-> R.geom
     limit 1);
```

which in procedural thinking would be the equivalent to:

> *for every row `R` of `parcels`, find the row in `intersections`
>   whose `geom` is the nearest to `R.geom` and copies its `osm_id` into
>   `R.nearest_intersection`*

---

On the other hand, if it had to be done with a loop, it would look like this:

```
FOR var_gid IN SELECT gid FROM parcels 
LOOP
UPDATE parcels SET nearest_intersection = 
    (select intersection.osm_id
     from intersections
     order by
     intersections.geom <-> parcels.geom)
     limit 1)
  WHERE parcels.gid=var_gid;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I will test this in the morning.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I was wondering if you could shed some light on why with 28747 rows the function I wrote takes 6245 seconds while the update query takes 7002 seconds.  I though the update would be faster...

Comment: @tapzx2: what's in your function at this point? Also `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the queries would be necessary to compare their  executions plans.

Comment: Thank you again Daniel, EXPLAIN ANALYZE answered my question.  I'll be using that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Don't be a hostage of SQL purism. Write functions with loops. When you are a postgres expert you'll change them to queries. Or not.

You probably missed WHERE clause for UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks klin, I went ahead and successfully quote and executed my query.  It looks like Daniel Vérité, a sql expert, has solved my problem for me.  But your words have left a lasting impression.